An iframe which has both allow-scripts and allow-same-origin for its sandbox attribute can escape its sandboxing
Unable to render Google Pay in Stripe Payment Elements, When we try to Integrate Stripe Payment Elements , Google Pay is not rendering even if its US ip address ,
Getting this error
An iframe which has both allow-scripts and allow-same-origin for its sandbox attribute can escape its sandboxing. 


Can you confirm if you fulfil the pre-requisite for Google Pay?

Your page is served through HTTPs
You logged in your Google account
Your Google wallet has an active card
You are from a country where Google Pay is supported (i.e., not from India or China)


Your page is served through HTTPs - Done
You logged in your Google account - Done
Your Google wallet has an active card - Active Card Means
You are from a country where Google Pay is supported (i.e., not from India or China) - Done
Can you please confirm on Active card

Open https://payments.google.com/gp/w/u/0/home/paymentmethods and make sure you have added a valid card to your Google Pay wallet

It is for US based google account , @qichuan

Ok, one last thing. Have you registered your domain for Payment Methods? https://docs.stripe.com/payments/payment-methods/pmd-registration

It was working fine for us based google account ,
